# Valid or Invalid state in mySql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a piece of code below and according to a condition I wanted to know why the question is invalid

```
CREATE VIEW HotelBookingCount (hotelNo, bookingCount)
AS  SELECT h.hotelNo, COUNT(*)
FROM Hotel h, Room r, Booking b
WHERE h.hotelNo = r.hotelNo AND r.roomNo  b.roomNo
GROUP BY h.hotelNo;
```

The question is :

```
SELECT hotelNo
FROM HotelBookingCount
WHERE bookingCount > 1000;
```

When I type it shows error
What is the logic behind this? Why I am not supposed to do this?

Comment: Add error message OR notification with question

Comment: Are you trying to pass arguments to `view`?

Comment: Yeah I am @Sougata is hotelNo, bookingCount. Is it because of bookingCount why is not working ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `VIEW`s that way and also there is nothing to pass the arguments as they are unused. Try with -

```
CREATE VIEW HotelBookingCount 
AS  SELECT h.hotelNo, COUNT(*) bookingCount
FROM Hotel h, Room r, Booking b
WHERE h.hotelNo = r.hotelNo AND r.roomNo  b.roomNo
GROUP BY h.hotelNo;
```

Then

```
SELECT hotelNo
FROM HotelBookingCount
WHERE bookingCount > 1000;
```